# Popover Segue Cocoa Storyboard changing position in Xcode 7 Beta 6 on El Capitan

Tags: xcode, cocoa, storyboard

This is a pretty specific question, but Xcode 7 Beta 6 on El Capitan seems to change the way Popover Segues are anchored. Instead of anchoring from a button, per se, the popover anchors from the enclosing view. Anyone else experienced this and or figured out a way to solve it?

For example this is a new project with a button, the popover displays from the top of the view even though the segue is anchored to the button.

[image]

Comment: Yes, I'm seeing the same behavior. Hunting around for a solution now…

Comment: @theory I just rewrote my app to create the popover programmatically. Kinda annoying, but it works fine now.

https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/samplecode/Popover/Introduction/Intro.html

Comment: Did you file a radar for the issue, @charlie-deets?

Comment: I reported it in [rdar://22690997](http://openradar.appspot.com/radar?id=4937205499822080).

Comment: @theory yup, I had reported it. rdar://22475993

Comment: Mine was marked as a duplicate of rdar://22436455 and closed. Xcode will be updated soon I hope!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Unfortunately this still happens with Xcode 7.0.1 and El Capitan 10.11 so we need to do this programmatically as stated in the comments. This code snippet might help:

```swift
class ViewController: NSViewController {

    var popover = NSPopover()

    @IBOutlet var button: NSButton?

    @IBAction func pressButton(sender: AnyObject?) {
        let mainStoryboard: NSStoryboard = NSStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil)
        guard let windowController = mainStoryboard.instantiateControllerWithIdentifier("Popover") as? NSViewController else { return }

        popover.contentViewController = windowController
        popover.behavior = .Transient
        popover.showRelativeToRect(button!.bounds, ofView: sender as! NSView, preferredEdge: .MaxY)
    }

}
```

Comment: Version 7.2 (7C68)...  still not working using only storyboards... :( Good solution!